# How can I pass the all constructor value into parent class in python

Tags: python

I have one parent class that's constructor takes some arguments to initialize and want the same constructor in the child class and add more parameters to it

```
# Parent class
class Parent:
    def __init__(
            self,
            name: str = None,
            state: str = False,
            dry_run: bool = False
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.state = state
        self.dry_run = dry_run

# Child class

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__()
```

I have tried to add all the parameters manually using `super.init(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: I assume `name` in `Child` should be an argument/attribute that isn't already in `Parent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add *args and **kwargs inside def int and super init  like this

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then your inheritance should work

```
child_instance = Child(name="Child Name", state=True, dry_run=True)
```

Comment: Going a step further, it's not recommended to use positional arguments at all for `__init__`, as confusion can arise as to which positional arguments in the call to `Child` are intended for which ancestor class.